# How to avoid absolute bottom positioned div from overlapping other when window is resized

Tags: html, css

I have a page where I have a div at the bottom of the page which when clicked shows another div, just above the bottom div.

I'd like to avoid the footer divs overlapping the content div higher up the page when the window is resized.

The heights of the divs involved shouldn't change.

Is a CSS-only solution possible?

I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5bkznxud/3/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid #aaa 1px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#content {
  height: 300px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

#footer-content {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  display:none;
}

#footer-footer {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid cyan 1px;
}

#footer.expanded #footer-content {
  display:block;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="container">
   <div id="content">content
    </div>
   <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-content">footer-content</div>
    <div id="footer-footer">Click me to expand</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#footer-footer").on("click", function (evt) {
  $("#footer").toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

Comment: I think remove position

Comment: Would you prefer to have a 100px empty space where the footer shows or rather the "Click me to expand" sliding down?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak - Not sure to be honest, but I think I would prefer to have a 100px empty space.

Comment: @user5325596 ok, see my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `position: relative` to the #container. This way the absolute positioning of the footer refers to the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/5bkznxud/5/

You'll probably notice that in the example above there's always a scrollbar on the right. This is because of the borders and padding on #container. Here's an example with outline (border with no calculated width) and without any padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/5bkznxud/6/

**TIP:** Always use outline instead of border for blocking a layout OR use `box-sizing: border-box`. This causes a box' dimensions to also calculate for the border. Otherwise a box with width of 100% and border will span slightly wider than you want.

Comment: Looks good, thanks. I'd come up with the following "solution" - http://jsfiddle.net/5bkznxud/8/ - using a wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by using `calc()`.
In this case you can create a jQuery function that get the height of `footer-content` and `footer-footer` -> `.height()`. Without jQuery, I don't think it's possible.

Here is an example:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid #aaa 1px;
    padding: 4px;
    min-height: 420px;

}

#content {
    height:calc(100% - 135px);
    border: solid blue 1px;
}

#footer-content {
    height: 100px;
    border: solid red 1px;
    display:none;
}

#footer-footer {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 20px;
    border: solid cyan 1px;
}

#footer.expanded #footer-content {
    display:block;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dokmngv0/

Browser support for the `calc()` feature: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: When I resize your fiddle I can still make the footer overlap the content. I'll also edit my question to make it clear that the `content` div shouldn't be resized.

Comment: Yes that's true, because you should manually get the height of both footer elements to be sure to have the right value. I put 135px arbitrarily